# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed Error for Rest API

Tags: java, rest

Am asking this question after doing some research. I did followed the solutions given for this kind of error but did not work for me. Any suggestions as where am going wrong in the below code.I am creating a REST API but when I request the url it is giving me the 405 error.Below is the URI am requesting.

```
    http://localhost:8080/Project/services/start/version
```

Below is the code snippet.

```
@Path("/start")

public class StartService {
@GET
@Path("/version")
@Produces({"text/plain","application/xml","application/json"})
public String getVersion() {
    String ver="";

    try{


          Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
          Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\server\\dgr -v" );

          BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
(pr.getInputStream()));
          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(stdInput);
         // String ver ="";
          StringBuffer verOutput = new StringBuffer();
                while((ver =  input.readLine()) != null){
                    verOutput.append(ver + "\n");
                    System.out.println(ver);
                }


        }catch (Throwable t)  
          {  
            t.printStackTrace();  
          }  


        finally {  

        }
    return ver;  }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<servlet>
<display-name>eLicensingWeb</display-name>      
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.cem.plc.service</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>




<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you using HTTP GET to access the URL?

Comment: 405 usually means you either tried a GET on something that only allows POST, or vice-versa, or tried http: on a method that requires https

Comment: @Kevin:Thanks for the quick reply. I tried with post but no luck. Atlease with GET it was printing the output in the console with system.out.println but with POST it is not even printing the output in the console.

Comment: I again changed it to GET,now the 405 error is gone but I dont see any output in the uri page where as in I can still see that system.out.println is printing the output in the console. Any suggestions

Comment: The 405 you were getting was due to the fact that you've only defined @GET on the method. As for not returning anything, what are you using to test results? Perhaps you'd like to use TDD for this since Jersey has its own test framework. Also, I think you're using an older version of Jersey.

Comment: @Kevin Ty for explaining the meaning of 405 in so simple language. It helped me in debugging.

Comment: @user2821894 Did you solve it? I am also getting 405 method not allowed when I do POST. It's like "@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)".... How to give access to client to even post/put/etc.

Comment: when I change to `get` method I get 403 forbidden error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Produces({"text/plain","application/xml","application/json"})
```

change this to

```
@Produces("text/plain")
```

and try,

Comment: Why? This answer doesn't explain what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Please explain it detaily

Comment: please explain this details. i am also have the similar problem.

Answer (score 25):

You might be doing a PUT call for GET operation
Please check once

Comment: The accepted answer shows that this was a `Content-Type` issue.  Why do you think it's an issue with the HTTP action?

Comment: Use "PUT" instead of "GET"

Answer (score 6):

In above code variable "ver" is assign to null, print "ver" before returning and see the value. As this "ver" having null service is send status as "204 No Content".

And about status code "405 - Method Not Allowed" will get this status code when rest  controller or service only supporting GET method but from client side your trying with POST with valid uri request, during such scenario get status as "405 - Method Not Allowed"

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
@Produces({"image/jpeg,image/png"})
```

to

```
@POST
@Path("/pdf")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces({"image/jpeg,image/png"})
//@Produces("text/plain")
public Response uploadPdfFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and was able to solve it by enabling CORS support on the server. In my case it was an Azure server and it was easy: [Enable CORS on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript)

So check for your server how it works and enable CORS. I didn't even need a browser plugin or proxy :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the Url had portions of it missing
*For example :*

```
http://localhost:8080/root/path/action
```

*Instead I had something like*

```
http://localhost:8080/root/action
```

Take away is check if the URL is correct. In my case I corrected my URL and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

When I got 405 when making a rest call, I did all research and none worked for me. Finally I realized I did not put the right version of code in tomcat. Once the code with the method is in place, the rest call worked. Just want to put here FYI.
Please check your version of code first!!!!