# Sending request with JSON returns error 405 :Method not allowed

Tags: java, angularjs, json, resteasy

I am trying to send `intakeanswers.json` from AngularJS form by clicking on the Edit button to java web service but I am getting an ERROR:

> "405 Method not allowed".

Is my JSON fine?

AngularJS and HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myappp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="edit_ctrl">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myapp = angular.module('myappp', []);
            myapp.controller('edit_ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("data/intakeanswers.json").success(function(data) {
                    $scope.dataJson=data;
                });
                $scope.doEdit = function() {
                    $scope.dataJs = angular.copy($scope.dataJson);
                    var dat = angular.toJson($scope.dataJs);
                    alert("hi");
                    $http({
                         url: "http://localhost:8080/...../FormAnswers/Answers",
                         method: 'POST',
                         data: dat,
                         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/Json'},
                    })
                };          
            });
        </script>
        <button ng-click="doEdit()">Edit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java rest web service code:

```java
@Path("/FormAnswers")
public class FormAnswersService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FormAnswersService.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/Answers")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAnswers(String id) {
        try {       
            System.out.println(id);     
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());           
        }
        return "response";  
    }
}
```

JSON:

```json
{ 
    "User_Id": "abcd",
    "Form_Name": "Form",
    "Answers": [{
            "Question_Id": "1",
            "Answer" :"a"
        },
        {
            "Question_Id": "2",
            "Answer" :"b"
        },
        {
            "Question_Id": "3",
            "Answer" :"c"
        }
    ],
    "Section_Name": "Project Overview",
    "Answers": [{
            "Question_Id": "4",
            "Answer" :"d"
        },
        {
            "Question_Id": "5",
            "Answer" :"e"
        },
        {
            "Question_Id": "6",
            "Answer" :"f"
        }
    ]       
}
```

Comment: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/Json'},` should be `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` and btw why multiple Answers in your json?

Comment: this might help u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143971/http-status-405-method-not-allowed-error-for-rest-api

Comment: I changed the {'Content-Type': 'application/Json'} to{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}  but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your web service controller only declared a GET method implementation. You need to add the support for POST:

```
@POST
@Path("/Answers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setAnswers(String data) {

}
```

Since, your web-service doesn't support POST, 405 is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your web service code is expecting a GET request and you are sending a POST.

In this scenario I would expect a 405.

Change:

```
@GET
@Path("/Answers")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

To:

```
@POST
@Path("/Answers")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

As pointed out below however this will get you past the 405 (as you'll be using the correct http request method however your java service will still not work. You're endpoint is expecting a string and your POST'ing a json file. You will need to return a response and will need to parse the json within your java unless I'm very much mistaken. I have little experience with java and thus cannot help there.

Comment: i changed my method to GET in angularjs but still getting the same error

Comment: You'll need to change your Expected request type within the java file from GET to POST (and change the angular code back to POST, you can't send the json file with a GET request). Will update answer.

Comment: OP doesn't need to change the method type instead add the implementation for POST method

Comment: Actually you're right @RaunakAgarwal came here for the angular tag. Alas not a Java dev. Updating answer to reflect.

Answer (score -2):

If the service requires only a single value (id) to retrieve the answers, instead of sending a JSON, you can send the id alone using the params attribute. But this will expose the id in the url.

Sample : $http.get("/url/", {params:{"param1": val1, "param2": val2}})
.then(/* */)...

Note : To check what type of request is sent from the browser to the service, in chrome
1.Press Ctrl+F12. This opens up the debug dialogue.
2.Refresh the page or call the service.
3.In the network tab, all the request calls to the service will be recorded. click on the service url
4. On the right side the request details will be presented. In that select the Headers tab. Checkout the Request Method:attribute under General section
5. This will show you the type of request sent from the browser. This will confirm whether your changes got effect.

Comment: OP is trying to post the data and not retrieve information