# CORS preflight response doesn't change

Tags: cors

I'm getting a 405 error for a POST request, even though I have changed the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Allow. I have not been able to change the preflight response to anything other than HEAD, GET, OPTIONS.

I have changed Access-Control-Allow-Methods to "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS", I have changed it to "POST, OPTIONS" and I have changed it to "*". I have added `containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Allow", "HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS");` with and without `containerResponseContext.getHeaders().remove("Allow");`. I have also added `containerResponseContext.getHeaders().replace("Allow", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"HEAD", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"}));` and removed because it didn't work. Here is my current code:

```
package nl.han.oose.dea.rest.filters;

import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

@Provider
public class AccessControlResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().remove("Allow");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Allow", "HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2023 12:26:28 GMT
Allow: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 10
```

Everything I tried either completely broke everything or didn't do anything.

Comment: _I'm getting a 405 error for a POST request [...]_ That's not related to CORS. Besides, the `Allow` header is only an indication for the benefit of the client. It doesn't guarantee that the resource actually supports the HTTP methods listed.

Comment: good to know that I got different things to try out then, but what is it related to? I can't change that it is a POST request

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I figured it out with help of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759172/sending-request-with-json-returns-error-405-method-not-allowed it helped a lot to look outside CORS