# HTTP Status 405 and Restful API in Flask Python

Tags: python, api, http, flask-restful, http-status-code-405

**The general goal**

For a webshop without frameworks I am working on, I need to define a good route to the restful API of the application.

**The problem**

When I load the page (for example: localhost:.../api/favorites) I get the HTTP 405 error with the message: "Method not allowed".

I have searched for different kinds of sources such as a forum post about the HTTP 405 error: [HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed Error for Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143971/http-status-405-method-not-allowed-error-for-rest-api). But I could not discover how this would solve my error.

And I have studied the 'Flask Documentation' and have found an example:

```
@app . url_defaults 
  def add_language_code ( endpoint , values ) : 
    if lang_code in values or not g . lang_code : 
      return 
    if app . url_map . is_endpoint_expecting ( endpoint , lang_code ) : 
      values [    lang_code ] = g . lang_code
```

*But I could not find what I am doing exactly wrong or is missing, and most important: why do I get that HTTP 405 error with this @api route.*

**Explanation of my project:**

In the database I have a table named '*favorites*' with the columns '*user_id*' and '*product_id*. On the /favorites page I want to load data from the favorites table to show the favorited items by a (specific) user.
But first of all I want just to import the data from the database.
I want to do this by retrieving the product_id from the database (first route). And later on I want to specify that it is only possible to favorite items when you have ordered it. (orderhistory or combined by user_id) (second route).

The front-end of the webshop is made with html/css/javascript and the back-end is flask by python.

**The question:**

***Is the error of the HTTP 405 message due to a fault in this piece of code that routes to the API?***

*Could someone understand and maybe explain my precise code mistake so I can try to fix it by knowing what is causing the error?*

First route

```
@api.route('/favorites/<int:product_id>', methods = ['GET'])
   def get_favorites(product_id):
      return favorites.get_favorites(product_id)
```

Second route

```
@api.route('/favorites/<int:user_id>')
   def get_favorites_by_user_id(user_id):
     return favorites.get_favorites_by_user_id(user_id)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you share the link when your project is finidhed? I am interested in building a Flask based webshop. Have you already tried something like this http://pythonhosted.org/flask-itemshop/#

Comment: @saitam the schoolproject is not published online but different variations can be found on GitHub with the terms _'flask web'_ and _'project'_ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you can show your front end code. But I think you made a post request to the backend without listing `methods=['GET', 'POST']` in your logic. Thus getting a 405.

Just add the POST to your list

Comment: Oh I think that should solve the problem. Do you mean something like this: adding a new route with the POST method?

_@api.route('/favorites', methods=['POST'])
def post_favorites(favorites):
    return favorites.post_favorites(favorites)_ 

Because I still get the same error.

Comment: @Sophievda Ha glad that worked! That was really an intuitive guess lol. It would be nice if you can accept.